# How to register just the major version of an OpenShift cluster?

Tags: ansible, openshift, ansible-2.x

```yaml
- name: get ocp version
  shell: "oc get clusterversion | awk '{print $2}'| tail -1"
  register: ver
```

I have used above task to register the output in Ansible task, but `ver` will have minor version as well - `4.8.1`, I need only major version i.e., `4.8`.

Comment: this might help `oc get clusterversion |awk 'END{split($2,a,".");print a[1] "." a[2]}'`

Comment: it helped but, not working in shell module, may have to use escape characters I believe    The offending line appears to be:

     - name: get ocp version
        shell: "oc get clusterversion |awk 'END{split($2,a,".");print a[1] "." a[2]}'"
                                                        ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
unbalanced quotes. If starting a value with a quote, make sure the
line ends with the same set of quotes. For instance this arbitrary
example:

    foo: "bad" "wolf"

Could be written as:

    foo: '"bad" "wolf"'

Comment: remove double quotes from the start and end of the command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, Note that the command is not wrapped in double quotes.

```
- name: get ocp version
  shell: oc get clusterversion | awk 'END{split($2,a,".");print a[1] "." a[2]}'
  register: ver
```

Answer (score 3):

Q: ***"I need only major version i.e., 4.8"***

A: Given the registered variable

```yaml
  ver.stdout: 4.8.1
```

the simplest option is to use the filter *splitext*. For example,

```yaml
  ver_major: "{{ ver.stdout|splitext|first }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  ver_major: '4.8'
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `grep`

```bash
oc get clusterversion --no-headers | grep -o '[4].[0-9]' | head -1
```

directly, for the version only, an option with `cut`

```bash
oc get clusterversion -o jsonpath='{.items[].spec.desiredUpdate.version}{"\n"}' | cut -d '.' -f -2
```

which will both result into

```
4.8
```

If you are interested in the specs or [upgrade channels and releases](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.8/updating/understanding-upgrade-channels-release.html) of your OpenShift Cluster Distribution

```yaml
  - name: OC get upgrade channel
    shell:
      cmd: oc get clusterversion -o jsonpath='{.items[].spec.channel}{"\n"}'
    # Since this is a reporting task ...
    changed_when: false
    check_mode: false
    register: ver
```

which would result into

```
stable-4.8
```

More interesting information ...

```bash
oc get clusterversion -o jsonpath='{.items[]}{"\n"}' | jq .
```

**Further Documentation**

- [Gathering data about your cluster](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/openshift_container_platform/4.8/html/support/gathering-cluster-data)
- [OpenShift Admins Guide to `jsonpath`](https://access.redhat.com/articles/2988581)